# Return images from storage folder

Tags: laravel

I have some images in the storage folder. I want to get them in response and show to my users.

**What I try:**

I use the following code but it returns `NULL`:

```
// All images are in the storage/app/users/{id}/document folder
$path = storage_path( 'app/users/'.$id . '/document');
if (!File::exists($path)) {
    abort(404);
} 
$file = File::files($path);
$type = File::mimeType($path);
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);
return $response;
```

> Output: Null

- Where is my mistake?
- Is there a better solution?

Comment: Don't you know the name of file?

Comment: @akshaypjoshi I'm using `File:files`, This will cause all files to be returned.

Comment: Laravel version?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto `6.4.0 version`.

Comment: `File::files()` will return all files in the directory. Returning multiple images as a single binary `Response()` does not make sense ... are you trying to return them all, or just 1?  If you want to return them all, why not just return the array of `$files`, and in your view display each with `<img src="...">`?

Comment: Is symlink already allowed in your server?

Comment: @user10971804 Yes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I returned an array of files. Although the length of the return array is the same as the number of files in the directory, all its elements are null. Can you show me an example?

Comment: [`return Storage::files($path);`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#directories)

Answer (score 1):

By the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#directories)

you can resolve this.

```php
return Storage::files('users/'.$id .'/document')
```

the default path of store file in laravel is `storage/app/public` and by default you should not set this path and your path is after this and laravel by default start from this path

and remember to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`
in top of your class